# Laravel: Any route starting with the letter 'a' throws error

Tags: php, laravel, .htaccess, url-rewriting, routes

I currently have .htaccess rewriting subdomains to load laravel .env files. using

```
SetEnvIf Host "^(.*)\.(.*)\.com" APP_TENANT=$1
```

Which loads .env.APP_TENANT

This works for all subdomains so far, except any subdomain starting with the letter 'a', like

> a, anywhere, agnostic, aim - any assets keep showing 404 error!

The funny thing is subdomains that don't start with 'a'

> nywhere, gnostic, all load the assets properly!

Which I just cannot for the life of me figure out why. I have no single letter regex routes.

Can someone help me please? I am stumped and spent many hours on this to no avail.

Thank you in advance

Comment: i don't know the answer exactly. I have been waiting for a time. But in my opinion. It's related "^" letter. "^" about first string values you specified. Maybe it could be missing first letter. But if your mistake is really about first letter, error reason could be "^" letter.